# Clear Textarea after Ajax Response while using clEditor

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, textarea, cleditor

I am trying to clear value of text-area using `cleditor`. but its not clear after the ajax response. My code are below:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="cleditor/jquery.cleditor.css" />
<script src="cleditor/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="cleditor/jquery.cleditor.min.js"></script>
<script>$(document).ready(function () { $("#desc").cleditor(); });
</script>
//Ajax Response Function
success: function(response)
    {

        $("#btnSubmit").attr('value', 'Add');
        $("#frm_data")[0].reset();
        $("#Comman").show();
   }
<label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Description:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
    <textarea rows="5" cols="5" name="desc" id="desc" class="form-control"> </textarea>
    </div>
```

Please let me know what can I do for clear the text area value on ajax response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#desc").cleditor()[0].clear();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/M2RS8/495/

Comment: thanks.. i try it. but value not clear. if i am not use cl-editor than its working fine

Comment: @Meenapatel now check

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: CLEDITOR is not defined

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: options is not defined

Comment: hi simple solution now checked that

Comment: You Great. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can clear the textarea field by assigning the empty value to textarea field.
its work 100% for me, i hope its also work for you.

```
$('#desc').val('');
```

Comment: thanks.. i try it. but value not clear. if i am not use cl-editor than its working fine.

Comment: can you use this method.
var editor = $("#desc").cleditor(options)[0]; 
editor.clear();

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: options is not defined

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).cleditor(...).clear is not a function

Answer (score 0):

For this try something like $("#desc").val("");

```
$("#desc").val("");
```

Here #desc is the id of the textarea you want to clear and .val(' ') sets it's value to ' ' - notice the space between the ';